# Show Progress Bar for Django WeasyPrint PDF Export

Tags: django, pdf, export, weasyprint

I am using WeasyPrint to create a PDF. The PDFs can easily reach over 120 pages and can take up to 2 minutes to render. While this happens, the page looks frozen and is not responsive. I am looking into Celery but until I get there I would like to implement a progress bar:

**Perfect Solution:**
Somehow grab the current status of the PDF export and show it in a progress bar

**Acceptable Solution**: 
Show a moving progress bar that is telling the user that it might take up to two minutes until the PDF shows up in the browser display / downloads itself.

Any ideas? Thanks!

current views.py:

```
def course_view(request):
    students = Student.objects.filter(student_courseid__course_accid = request.user.userprofile.course_accid)

    html_template = get_template('student/student_pdf_all.html')
    rendered_html = html_template.render({'student': students}, request)
    pdf_file = HTML(string=rendered_html, base_url=request.build_absolute_uri()).write_pdf(stylesheets=[CSS(settings.STATIC_ROOT +  '/css/pdf.css')])

    http_response = HttpResponse(pdf_file, content_type='application/pdf')
    filename = str(request.user.userprofile.course_accid) + ".pdf"

    http_response['Content-Disposition'] = 'filename="{}"'.format(filename)

    return http_response
```

Answer (score 0):

To get exact progress, you would have to hit backend again and again using an ajax call at some url. The view connected to the url is ofcourse not connected to the main views responsible for conversion. Therefore you would have to store progress in database. (for a 2 min job this seems senseless to me).

On top of this, extracting current progress from the process and storing in the database would be another headache.

Since you are sure it is at max a 2 or 3 min job, make a javascript loader in the frontend script, while at a fixed interval (maybe 20 sec) hit the backend to see if the file has been created or not. If it has been created redirect to show the pdf (or whatever you want) else keep the progressing loading sign (which completes in 3 min maybe).

(Everything that i'm explaining happens on the same page using ajax, else you would have to use python async methods)

When the user submits request for pdf, call the view (via ajax) to create pdf and start the loader thing as mentioned before.

You can extend this to use python's threading and won't need celery unless you want to monitor that task.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Can you point me to some resources where "hitting the backend" is explained? I currently don't have any idea how I would do that.

Comment: Sorry, by hitting the backend, I mean making ajax calls to a url. You can find numerous examples for that (django with ajax).